# Should try catch TypeScript assertion function?

Tags: typescript, assertion

I create a TS assertion function, Later, I use it before passing the request DTO to the API service in a UI event handler.

```
function assertIsGetCampaignPackageReqDTO(
  value: any,
): asserts value is GetCampaignPackageRuquestDTO {
  if (!value.campaignId || !value.packageCode) {
    throw new Error('campaignId or packageCode is empty!');
  }
}

const onSearchFormSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    assertIsGetCampaignPackageReqDTO(searchCondition);
    const { value } = await getCampaignPackageQuery.execute(searchCondition);
    if (value?.code === '0') {
      setCampaignPackages(campaignPackages.concat(value.result));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    message.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

Should I use `try...catch` statement with the assertion function and show the error message to users? Or, I should validate the legality(`if` statement) of the request DTO before using the assertion function. The assertion function is only used for passing the TSC check?

Or this:

```
function assertIsGetCampaignPackageReqDTO(
  value: any,
): asserts value is GetCampaignPackageRuquestDTO {
  if (!value.campaignId || !value.packageCode) {
    throw new Error('value is not GetCampaignPackageRuquestDTO');
  }
}

const onSearchFormSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!searchCondition.campaignId || !searchCondition.packageCode) {
    return message.error('campaignId or packageCode is empty!');
  }
  assertIsGetCampaignPackageReqDTO(searchCondition);
  const { value } = await getCampaignPackageQuery.execute(searchCondition);
  if (value?.code === '0') {
    setCampaignPackages(campaignPackages.concat(value.result));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume all you want is to catch exceptions instead of letting your program be crashed.

- If the code in function `assertIsGetCampaignPackageReqDTO` is exactly the same as in `if condition`, then you should choose one of those methods. I prefer using `if condition` for simplicity.
- If there are other checks in assert function, you should use both: try catch and if condition. Using `if` if you want to catch separate cases such as `campaignId` and `packageCode` (as shown in your code).  And using `try catch` to catch other failure cases.

```
if (!searchCondition.campaignId || !searchCondition.packageCode) {
    return message.error('campaignId or packageCode is empty!');
}

try {
    assertIsGetCampaignPackageReqDTO(searchCondition);
    const { value } = await getCampaignPackageQuery.execute(searchCondition);
    if (value?.code === '0') {
      setCampaignPackages(campaignPackages.concat(value.result));
    }
} catch (error) {
    message.error(error.message);
}
```

Comment: Additional info along with the above answer, You could typecast any variable using ```as <type>``` that will be the tsc check. The code inside assert function is actually checking if the necessary property are present in object, so it's a check in javascript too!